# asp.net how to pass list of items to eval function?

Tags: c#, asp.net

this is my code to view products as list view inside each item in list view  i want to view list of items  how can i do this? i can not understand the concept of the eval function and i want to know if i can pass to it list items from code behind without data Bind or it basically depends on  data-bind ?

```
  <asp:ListView ID="mylistView" runat="server" GroupItemCount="3">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table id="Table2" runat="server">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <EmptyItemTemplate>
                <td id="Td3" runat="server" />
            </EmptyItemTemplate>
            <GroupTemplate>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                    <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </GroupTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table border="0" width="300" style="display: inline-block; background-color: Lime;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href='ContactUs.aspx'>
                                <image src='productsImg/<%# Eval("Pic_Path") %>' width="100" height="75" border="0">
                            </a>&nbsp
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a><b style="text-decoration: underline;">
                                <%# Eval("MenuName") %></b> </a>
                            <br />

                          want to view here list of items 
                       I 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="Table1" runat="server">
                    <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                        <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                            <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                                <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
                        <td id="Td2" runat="server">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

this is code behind...

```
         dataSource.ConnectionString = connetionString;
    dataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tbl_WebMenu where MenuID like'3_';";
    mylistView.DataSource = dataSource;
    mylistView.DataBind();
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eval is used to bind to an UI control that is supposedly read only. it can be used to set any type of property of control. 
The complete syntax is "Databinder.Eval", it has to be used in conjunction with databind.
Look at this example.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblRead" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FieldName") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

you can even set a property of control using eval. it provides flexibility.

But there is a downside of eval as it uses reflection to evaluate the expression.
Read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx#remarksToggle

Comment: but this code view only one item i want to view list of items not one on label text

Comment: Instead you can have your View template as plain HTML and iterate thro your items in array to display it in .aspx.  <%foreach item in arrays { %> <asp:label text = <%item.value %> <%}%>